# How to parse a Ref GUID to a DataContext stored procedure

Tags: c#, .net

I currently have a DataContext using a stored procedure. The problem is the very last value, keeps giving me the following error message when trying to pass in a GUID value.

> Argument 13 must be passed with the 'ref' keyword.

Code used:

```
 Guid g;
 g = Guid.NewGuid();

 testDBAthDataContext dataOut = new testDBAthDataContext();

 dataOut.aspnet_Membership_CreateUser("APPNAME", "test@test.com", pass, passSalt, "test@test.com", "test Quest", "test Awr", true, saveNowDt, createdDt, null, null, g);
```

testDBAth.designer.cs Code layout of the "aspnet_Membership_CreateUser" arguments used.

```
IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), applicationName, userName, password, passwordSalt, email, passwordQuestion, passwordAnswer, isApproved, currentTimeUtc, createDate, uniqueEmail, passwordFormat, userId);
            userId = ((System.Nullable<System.Guid>)(result.GetParameterValue(12)));
            return ((int)(result.ReturnValue));
```

Comment: As error says you need to change `g` for `ref g` in the end of  your parameter list.

Comment: If i change the end parameter I get: "Argument 13: cannot convert from 'ref System.Guid' to 'ref System.Guid?'".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by, forgetting to add the ? on the Guid variable.

so the code now looks like:

```
Guid? g;
g = Guid.NewGuid();
```

And also added the ref to the end value. As suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/users/3179310/m-rogalski

Code below:

```
dataOut.aspnet_Membership_CreateUser("APPNAME", "test@test.com", pass, passSalt, "test@test.com", "test Quest", "test Awr", true, saveNowDt, createdDt, null, null, ref g);
```